# Connecting to Tab Bar View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have been following a tutorial to create a to-do list. I have a Tab Bar View Controller already managing 2 sets of Table View Controllers (WeekAViewController - item #1 & WeekBViewController - item 2).

Now, when I connect my Tab Bar View Controller to AllListsViewController (to become my 3rd set or item - code is down below), I get the following message in the debug window pointing to my AppDelegate:

**Could not cast value of type 'UITabBarController' (0x1ad56a0) to 'UINavigationController' (0x1ad5678).
(lldb)**

How could I resolve this issue, please? (App Delegate code below)

Thanks

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let dataModel = DataModel()


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let navigationController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
        let controller = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! AllListsViewController
        controller.dataModel = dataModel

        return true
    }

    ...

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        saveData()
    }

    ...

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        saveData()
    }

    func saveData() {
        dataModel.saveChecklists()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and put it in your `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` (hints are in the code comments):

```
// first find the UITabBarController
let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

// then look at its viewControllers array
if let tabBarViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers {
    // the reference to the AllListsViewController object
    let allListsViewController = tabBarViewControllers[0] as! AllListsViewController
    allListsViewController.dataModel = dataModel
}
```

**Edit regarding to the Comments (hints are in the code comments):**

```
// first find the UITabBarController
let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

// then look at its viewControllers array
if let tabBarViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers {

    // your AllListsViewController is in a NavigationController so get the right NavigationController
    // you can see the order of your added NavigationControllers in your storyboard in your case its the third
    // because tabBarViewControllers is an array the NavigationController where your AllListsViewController is, is at index 2
    let navigationController = tabBarViewControllers[2] as! UINavigationController

    // after you get the right NavigationController get the reference to your AllListsViewController
    let allListsViewController = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! AllListsViewController
    allListsViewController.dataModel = dataModel
}
```

Comment: I tried it and I have got the following message: Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1b41cec) to 'SchoolTime.AllListsViewController' (0x1daf58) - any thoughts?

Comment: Could you print the tabBarViewControllers at the top in the if let block with `print("TabBarViewControllers: \(tabBarViewControllers)")` and what Output do you get when you start your app after adding this?

Comment: I get the following output: TabBarViewControllers: [<UINavigationController: 0x7d3cbe00>, <UINavigationController: 0x7c3cce00>, <UINavigationController: 0x7c3d2800>]
Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1b0bcec) to 'SchoolTime.AllListsViewController' (0x1a4f58).
(lldb)

Comment: ok and now could you replace the print statement with these three print statements 

   `print("TabBarViewControllers childs of 0 \(tabBarViewControllers[0].childViewControllers)")`,
   `print("TabBarViewControllers childs of 1 \(tabBarViewControllers[1].childViewControllers)")`,
   `print("TabBarViewControllers childs of 2 \(tabBarViewControllers[2].childViewControllers)")` ?
Just to figure out where your AllListsViewController is

Comment: It won't let me run it - does not like the first comma... Not sure why. I have got an Expected declaration statement at the end too. The first 'print' is blue & the 2 other are black.

Comment: There is no comma. Just put the print statements like in this [link](http://imgur.com/5urckxC) and what output to you get after restarting?

Comment: The debug says: TabBarViewControllers childs of 0 [<SchoolTime.WeekAViewController: 0x788904f0>]
TabBarViewControllers childs of 1 [<SchoolTime.WeekBViewController: 0x78971a70>]
TabBarViewControllers childs of 2 [<SchoolTime.AllListsViewController: 0x7867e6e0>]
Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1aeccec) to 'SchoolTime.AllListsViewController' (0x185f68).
(lldb)

Comment: Ok nice, now you should be able to fix your problem. I will update my answer. In the meantime you can delete your print statements in your code

Comment: Ok, just updated my answer regarding to the comments. Let me know if it works now

Comment: You absolutely nailed it - it works!!! In all fairness, I would never have been able to solve this by myself. How do I vote for your valuable help on the website?

Comment: Yeah, glad that I could help you! You can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) how to vote and accept an answer

Comment: Cool - I think I did it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your main UITabBarController is not a UINavigationController. It inherits from UIViewController, just as UINavigationController. Which mean you can not write

```
let navigationController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
```

because you can not cast a UITabBarController in a UINavigationController.
You could try

```
let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
```

and use tabBarController afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

What you did wrong was here:

```
let navigationController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
```

The error says that a `UITabBarController` cannot be casted, or converted, to a `UINavigationController`, which is *exactly* what you are doing here.

In the storyboard, you said you connected 3 (table) view controllers to a tab bar view controller. And I assume that the app starting point is at the tab bar view controller. This means that `window!.rootViewController` is a `UITabBarController`!

Now that we know what is going on, let's see why this error occurred. The reason is simple, you are casting something to something that it isn't. `window!.rootViewController` is of type `UITabBarController`, right? So why are you casting it to `UINavigationController`? They are *completely* two different things!

So to fix the error, just cast the thing to `UITabBarController` instead:

```
let navigationController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
```

Also, I think you should change the variable names:

```
let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
let controller = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! AllListsViewController
...
```

Furthermore, you can be safer if you try this:

```
let tabBarController = window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController
if let vc = tabBarViewController {
    let controller = navigationController.viewControllers[0] as! AllListsViewController
    ...
} else {
    print("The root view controller is not a tab bar controller!")
}
```

Notice the `as?` instead of `as!` there? This will return nil if the cast did not succeed. I then used optional binding to check whether it is nil. If it is, output a message or something.